# YA book about teens with powers who attend a boarding school

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, powers

I remember the start of the book has the main character doing an exam I think, then they have to go to this school. I think they were adopted. I remember him having mental powers and making friends with others at the school as they figure out something to do with experiments. There's a lot of prowling around underground labs or hidden spaces I remember. Possibly a bit of romance as well. Sorry for how sporadic the info is I barely remember reading this at all. I was only like 9 or 10 at the time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was it that you read this?  (We don't know how old you are now.)  Was it set in a contemporary world, near future, alternate past?

Comment: I read it around ten years ago, it was set in present times.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example; What was the main character's name? How old was he? Who was administering the exam? What kind of exam was it? What was the school called? What happened to his parents? Who was the romance with? What was her name? How old was she? What kind of powers did he have? How did he use them? Was there a villain? What did they do? Was this school based in the UK or the US or somewhere else? What language did you read this book in? What did the front cover look like? Was the author male or female? Was the book aimed at youngsters or older teens?

Comment: Harry Potter? :P

Comment: It sounds a bit like "The Magicians" but that's an adult book with college-aged characters.

Answer (score 1):

[Dark Visions](https://www.simonandschuster.com/series/Dark-Visions) trilogy by L. J. Smith? The protagonist can see into the future, which she accesses by drawings. I think she's doing this in class at the start of the book.